# How to animate a specific instance of a class?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Below is a snippet of what I'm working on. It will basically be a large grid of images that have an opaque overlay covering them. I want each specific overlay to animate out when I hover  the div's image. I also need to make sure that only one image DOES NOT have the overlay at a time.

How do I go about doing this?

```
<div id="cast-wrap">
    <div id="img-wrap">
    <div class="char"><div class="overlay"></div><img style="z-index: 99999999;" src="img/person1.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="char"><div class="overlay"></div><img src="img/person2.jpg"/></div>
    <div class="char"><div class="overlay"></div><img src="img/person3.jpg"/></div>
</div>
```

This is what I tried doing...

```
$(".char").hover(
    if($("this.char img").css("z-index") == "0px"){ 
    $('this.overlay').animate({"opacity": 0});
    $('this.char img').animate({zIndex: 999999}, 2000)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The z-index will never be equal to "0px", as z-index is not a pixel value, nor should you need to use z-index in your javascript if you just remove the overlay by animating the opacity to zero on the overlay.

```
$(".char").on({
    mouseenter: function() {
        $('.overlay', this).animate({"opacity": 0}, 1000);
    },
    mouseleave: function() {
        $('.overlay', this).animate({"opacity": 1}, 1000);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't seem to work for me. Is there an alternative?

Comment: I just realized how easy it would be to do part of this with CSS - 

    .char:hover .overlay{
        display: none;
    }

I will just use jQuery for the click action. When an image is clicked, I want it's overlay to remain hidden.

Comment: Yes, affecting an element inside the hovered element can easily be done with css aswell.